# PHP & MySQL - LOAD DATA LOCAL issue

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm working on a small project in php to import a csv files into a MySQL table. I'm currently just using a small test table and csv however I keep getting an error thrown at me and I cant seem to spot it. I've looked at other peoples solutions and while there are differences I haven't found anything that should be stopping the import.

query is as follows:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$this->upload_name."' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE `testings` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
```

cvs is as follows

```
bob,builder,10,a
john,smith,5,a
happy,camper,8,a
johhny,ball,12,a
```

Table is as follows

```
fname  varchar(100)
sname  varchar(100)
copies  int(8)      
nowt  varchar(100)
```

Error is as follows

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\n'' at line 6
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm racking my head here trying to see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table names are not to be put in quotes. Use backticks in general or nothing if it is not a MySQL reserved keyword.

```
"LOAD DATA 
LOCAL INFILE " . $this->upload_name . "
IGNORE INTO TABLE `testings`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"
```

Comment: Cant believe I didn't notice that, not used to coding for hours! getting a different error now on the ESCAPED line.

Comment: @ChristopherFerguson Try using `'\\\\'` there.